# Using uninitialized memory

Tags: c

I'm learning C and I have one problem right now.

This is my part of code for a guessing number game, it's simple:

```
int secretNumber = 13;
int guess;

while (guess != secretNumber) {
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &guess);
}
printf("Win!");
```

And I receive the following errors:

> - Using uninitialized memory
> - uninitialized locar variable 'guess' used.
> - return value ignored 'scanf'.

Comment: Think: what's the value of `guess` in `while (guess != secretNumber)` before the first iteration of the loop happens?

Comment: So, i need to make that user first input number and then while loop?

Comment: "Using uninitialized memory" - that's exactly the problem. `guess` isn't initialized. In C, local variables do not have any specific value by default (such as `0`). This is undefined behaviour.

Comment: That, or give `guess` an initial value (`int guess = -1`).

Comment: One thing really confusing me here, because im watching one tutorial on youtube and learning, guy on tutorial write excatly same code and for him it works. Idk really

Comment: @evillaugh If it's exactly as you have here, then they're just ignoring the warning, which suggests that they aren't a good source to be learning from. This code will work *most of the time*, but without any guarentees.

Comment: There are no warning when he run the program.

Comment: C has been around a long time. Earlier standards have been less picky and compilers less adept in detecting program errors of the kind seen  in your program. so your tutorial video may simply be outdated. It certainly appears to do a poor job in introducing you to programming best practices. better spend your time _reading_ a decent book or web site.

Comment: While some implementations choose to init memory to some value (like 0x00 or 0xFF), none is required to do so. If you happen to use an implementation that doesn't care, and the value happens to be 13, the user will be informed that answer was wrong before the user even had the chance to enter an answer - a serious bug... Something similar applies to the missed return value - if the user doesn't enter a digit, behaviour is wrong. You wrote you're beginning. Please feel encouraged to continue practising - this is a typical mistake to start with - and a typical one to leave behind quite soon...

Comment: First Post REVIEW: There is something formal about your question - you didn't write what you actually want to receive help on. Would you like to know why you received the warning/error messages? Or, if the warning is correct / if it is justified? Or, what you have to do to pass the compile, intentionally ignoring those warnings? I've started fantasising a bit, but I'd like to ask you to write a central question to every "question" post - even if it looks quite trivial. B.t.w., you are always free to edit your posts at a later time. Thankyou for your attention, and welcome on Stack Overflow!

Comment: some compiler environments, like windows in DEBUG mode presets the stack to all 0x00.  However, that is a recipe for disaster when shifting to PRODUCTION mode.  (or using most any other environment besides Visual Studio)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is because the `guess` is uninitialized and you are comparing it in the while loop in the beginning.

In this case, it is better to construct it using in the `do {} while()` form. This way, the comparison is done after you got the value for the `guess` variable:

```c
int secretNumber = 13;
int guess;

do {

    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &guess);
} while (guess != secretNumber);

printf("Win!");
```

You are going to have some warning in the `scanf()` as well because you are not checking the return value.

To fix that as well, you can check like this:

```c
if (scanf("%d", &guess) != 1) {
    print("invalid input, try again\n");
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thats it. Thank you for explaing. Idk how then code that i post at first work for that guy on yt.

Comment: Probably he is ignoring the warnings from the compiler.